# Magento 2 - Import contacts emails .csv to newsletter suscribers

Tags: magento-2.1, import, newsletter, script

I have .csv in which have lot of email is exit, it want to assign those email to newsletter suscribers.

I have this

```
<?php
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$store_id = 1;
$csv_filepath = "subscribers.csv";
$csv_delimiter = ',';
$csv_enclosure = '"';
$magento_path = __DIR__;

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("subscribers.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        $status = $obj->get('Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber')->subscribe($data[$c]);
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
}
?>
```

It's work, but the problem is only import the first contact.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please share CSV files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
$status = $obj->get('Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber')->subscribe($data[$c]);
```

to

```
$status = $obj->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber')->subscribe($data[$c]);
```

Comment: HI! If my .csv have all emails in one line work! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you csv  like
[image]

Then

```
use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
$store_id = 1;
$csv_filepath = "subscribers.csv";
$csv_delimiter = ',';
$csv_enclosure = '"';
$magento_path = __DIR__;

$params = $_SERVER;

$bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $params);

$obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

$state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
$state->setAreaCode('frontend');

$websiteId =  $obj->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')
    ->getStore()
    ->getWebsiteId();

$customerAccountManagement =$obj
    ->create('Magento\Customer\Api\AccountManagementInterface');

$_subscriberFactory = $obj->create('Magento\Newsletter\Model\SubscriberFactory');


if (($handle = fopen("subscribers.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        // email Id
        $emailId = $data[0];
       /* customer */
        if($customerAccountManagement->isEmailAvailable($emailId , $websiteId)){
            echo $emailId ."Guest <br/>";
            $_subscriberFactory = $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribe($emailId );
        }else{
            echo $emailId ."Register <br/>";
            $customerFactory = $obj->get('Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerFactory');
            $customer=$customerFactory->create();
            $customer->setWebsiteId($websiteId);
            $customer->loadByEmail($emailId );// load customer by email address
            if($customer->getId()){
                $_subscriberFactory->create()->subscribeCustomerById($customer->getId());
            }

        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

***Note that:***

**Email server should work  other wise,it is not worked**

Comment: Thank you for  help! But i have the .csv how you display, but, don't work.

I receive this message.

mail01@mail.com Guest
mail02@mail.com Guest

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function create() on integer in import.php:36 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in impor6.php on line 36

Only import first email.